# Possible to discard touch events?

Tags: ios

I have a iOS game and during loading screens any touches the user does seem to be buffered up, so once the loading it done (it can take a few seconds), I get the touch events.

Is there way for me to discard all touches?

Comment: Does the program itself see the touch events during the load process or afterwards? If it is during you can set a variable (ie loaded) to false (set it to true when you are done loaded) and inside each touch event function check if loaded = false and if so exit the function before doing the code below.

Comment: I can't see the load events during the load because the event loop is not being pumped.  It's loading.  I was hoping to avoid fancy stuff and just clear all the events.

Comment: Sorry I haven't programmed ios. Just figured I would check the simpliest explanation. Good Luck

Comment: Have you tried setting user interaction enabled to NO before loading begins and setting it to yes after it loads?

Comment: That's a good idea.  I'll try that.

Comment: Any update on this? I tried the same but it seems that the touches are only delayed - they are gonna be sent as soon as I set user interaction enabled back to YES

Comment: No update. I am unable to discard touch events.  One approach would be to look at the time stamp of the touch event and discard it. This seems like a cumbersome approach.

Comment: it's not a question of discarding touch events. More a question of whether or not you want to consume them? Can you give us a bit more info and some code. Are there multiple "loading screens? Why not use the default splash? Are the loading screens each backed by a view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is a really old question but for anyone stumbling upon this can simply follow either of the below two approaches:

**Approach 1.**

```
DiscardTouchView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer())
```

Basically adding an empty gesture. So on tapping that view nothing happens.

**Approach 2.**

In this case you don't add empty gesture recognizer to the view. In case `DiscardTouchView` is a subview of `SomeParentView` which has a `UIGestureRecognizer` object, you can get that object and `ignore` it.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let tappedView = touches.first?.view else { return }
    if(tappedView == DiscardTouchView) {
        guard let recognizer = touches.first?.gestureRecognizers?.first else { return }
        recognizer.ignore(touches.first!, for: event!)
    }
}
```

Setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` actually passes the touch event from subview to superview. It doesn't discard the touch event.

Setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `true` for a simple `UIView` does the same.